# Heart Rate Variation on Android

Tags: java, android, heartrate

*How can I get the Heart Rate Variability using the Heart Sensor on Android?*

I managed to code an activity to measure the heart rate, but it seems that there is no way to do so for HRV. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

What I tried:

```
SensorManager manager=(SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        Sensor heart=manager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE);
        manager.registerListener(new SensorEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
                
            }
        },heart,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
```

The above code measures Heart Rate and not Heart Rate Variability.

**Definition of Heart Rate Variability:** HRV is the physiological phenomenon of the variation in the time interval between consecutive heartbeats in milliseconds.

I'm wondering if it is achievable knowing that I have the heart rate sensor on my Android device.

Comment: Might be a good idea to include some code you have tried and any errors you have encountered. Highly recommend checking [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: edited my question